# How to close connections in Requests (scalability)

Tags: python, python-requests

What is the equivalent of this, using the Requests library?

```
with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(request)) as response:
    return response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Requests seems to be a more modern solution for 2.7 than urllib2.

What would be the correct way to close the connections, so running the function 800 times or so, won't leave connections open and cause performance issues? Should I create a session and use close() on it?

Is it like this?

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
s.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) module. Could be handy to handle scalability.

Comment: The first question is are you sure there are open connection left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no connections open if you use requests in a very basic way. If you start using `stream=True` you will need to concern yourself with whether or not the entire response has been read, and whether or not it should then be closed. Otherwise, this should never be a concern of yours.

Comment: Ok, but in the first code snippet, urllib2 has to be closed like that right? So requests closes automatically, while urllib2 doesn't?